# Standard container for incomplete types

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, std

i'm having a little problem with containers and incomplete types.

I have this code:

```
template<typename T>
class IncompleteType
{ /*Class Definition*/ }
```

On another class i want to use a vector of incomplete types.
This class serializes c-style structs to strings, so the behaviour is the same, no matter what type i'm supplying.

However, when i do this:

```
std::vector<IncompleteType>
```

or this:

```
std::vector<IncompleteType*>
```

The compiler complains that i'm not supplying argument list for template class.

What i want to do is something like this:

```
IncompleteType<Type1> a;
IncompleteType<Type2> b;

std::vector<IncompleteType*> vector;

vector.push_back(&a);
vector.push_back(&b);
```

Is there a way to have a container to incomplete types?

Is this the wrong way to achieve polymorphism?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `std::vector<IncompleteType<my_type>>`

Comment: BTW your class declaration `class IncompleteType<T>` is not valid. C++ compiler would not compile it.

Comment: Since you mention polymorphism, beware that a `std::vector<Base>` where `Base` is a base type will induce object slicing if you try to store derived types.

Comment: @S.M. You're right, that's a typo. I Edited it :)

Comment: An incomplete type would be something like `class Incomplete;`. What you have here is a class template, it is not a type at all. You're probably mixing it up with something like the generics from Java or C#.

Comment: @liliscent But that's not what i want to do, i want to use it with any type i'm supplying. Is that possible?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux If i use pointers, there shouldn't be any problem right? Anyway, i'm not using Derived Types. Just a single template class.

Comment: @Fedelway Pointers would work, but prefer `std::unique_ptr`. If there is no inheritance, then why do you mention and tag `polymorphism` in your question? If you are trying to write a container that stores *any* kind of `IncompleteType` (with different template arguments) this approach won't work.

Comment: @Fedelway If you want a heterogeneous `vector`, consider inheritance and virtual function. Static typing is impossible.

Comment: "Is this the wrong way to achieve polymorphism?" yes, there is no way you reliably recover type of stored object back.

Comment: What you describe is not incomplete class, looks like you really do not understand what you want to achieve

Comment: @liliscent The problem is that i don't want inheritance, because the implementation would be exactly the same, which is what i'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have an incomplete type - you've got a class template there.  It often catches out people new to C++, but instantiations of that template with different types are (to the compiler/type system) *entirely unrelated*.

The template itself also isn't a "base class" of the instantiations - it cannot be used without supplying it's template type arguments.

As you're talking about "serializing to strings" I wonder if you're looking for the streaming operators instead - specifically streaming to string streams (see e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/overloading-the-output-operator-for-your-own-classes).

What happens there is that you overload the << operator for your own types and the type of stream you want, e.g.

```
std::ostringstream& operator<<(std::ostringstream& i_stream, const MyType& i_val) {
  i_stream << "( " << i_val.GetValue1() << ", " << i_val.GetValue2() << " )" << std::endl;
  return i_stream;
}
```

Then you can stream any kind of object into a string stream, as long as you've overloaded the stream operator for it.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try to circunvent this issue, shouldn't be hard. Thanks

Comment: Any particular reason for choosing `ostringstream` over `ostream`?

Comment: @Caleth - mostly because the original poster talked about streaming structs to strings.  A regular ostream might be used for binary streaming/archiving instead.